# PHP's preg_replace in bash, specific case

Tags: linux, bash, preg-replace, sh

I need to clean up a mysql dump containing PHP serialized values (I do a search/replace of urls using sed)

In PHP I would do it that way:

```
<?php

$ret_string = preg_replace('!s:(\d+):"(.*?)";!e', "'s:'.mb_strlen('$2').':\"$2\";'", $string );

?>
```

How would you do that in bash ?

Exemple original string:

```
a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:17:"http://myurl.com";s:7:"string2";s:‌​4:"test";}
```

I have already replaced myurl.com with mynewurl.com so it now lookas like:

```
a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:17:"http://mynewurl.com";s:7:"string2";s:‌​4:"test";}
```

What I need to change is the length of the string to reflect the length of the new string (s:17) for the for the final string to become:

```
a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:19:"http://mynewurl.com";s:7:"string2"‌​;s:4:"test";}
```

I have many of those in my sql dump which is a file on the file system. Although the domain has changed but the url may have an additional path,thus different string length

Comment: In bash you can call `php` using the `-r CODE` command-line option, but I would only do that for 1-liners because there's overhead in starting the PHP interpreter.  I was about to use `sed`, but then you're asking for a pure `bash` solution.

Comment: @YzmirRamirez: When people say "in Bash", they sometimes mean "pure Bash", but they more often mean common utilities such as `sed`, etc.

Comment: @Laurent: It would help if you showed some sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Dennis @Yzmir Yeah I just need to do it in a bash script, sed etc is ok.

Here is a string sample:

`a:3:s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:17:"http://myurl.com";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}`

I have already replaced http://myurl.com with http://mynewurl.com so its length (s:17) should be changed for the final string to become:

`a:3:s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:19:"http://mynewurl.com";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}`

I have many of those in my sql dump which is a file on the file system. Although the domain has changed but the url may have an additional path,thus different string length

Comment: +1 for editing your question.  You don't know how frustrating it is when people put their real question in the comments.  :-P

Comment: It looks very much like PHP serialized data, but it doesn't parse.  And I noticed a closing curly brace with no opening one.  Can you please verify your original string?

Comment: The missing opening brace doesn't matter, really, that code works as it: http://ideone.com/lCfWW

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up with a php -r solution. Doing this in bash would have been lots of lines I think:

```
mv "$DATA_DIR/final.sql" "$DATA_DIR/final.sql.1"
php -r  "echo preg_replace('!s:(\\d+):\\\\\\\"(.*?)\\\\\\\";!e', \"'s:'.strlen( str_replace (array('\\\\r', '\\\\n', '\\\\t'), ' ', '\$2') ) .':\\\\\\\"\$2\\\\\\\";'\", file_get_contents('$DATA_DIR/final.sql.1') );" >"$DATA_DIR/final.sql"
rm "$DATA_DIR/final.sql.1";
```

That works for my case.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with doing this in a regexp is that regexps are not suited to structured text like JSON or PHP serialized strings.  You can "fake" things if you know that your input data will ALWAYS follow a certain structure, but code written like that becomes problematic as things change over time.  And things always change over time.  If you can avoid this kind of hack, it's better to do so.

Exactly what problem are we trying to solve here?  Are you unable to run PHP on the host that needs to make this change?  Serialized data will be A LOT easier to handle in PHP, even if you make a tiny shell-executable PHP script to handle it.

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat indexrepl
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

// Usage: indexrepl index newcontent [string]

if ($argc < 4) {
  $s='a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:16:"http://myurl.com";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}';
} else {
  $s=$argv[3];
}

$a=unserialize($s);
$a[$argv[1]]=$argv[2];

print serialize($a) . "\n";

[ghoti@pc ~]$ 
[ghoti@pc ~]$ 
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./indexrepl url http://example.com/
a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:19:"http://example.com/";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ 
[ghoti@pc ~]$ s='a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:4:"test";s:3:"url";s:19:"http://example.com/";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}'
[ghoti@pc ~]$ ./indexrepl string1 foo "$s"
a:3:{s:7:"string1";s:3:"foo";s:3:"url";s:19:"http://example.com/";s:7:"string2";s:4:"test";}
```

**UPDATE:** wrapping this in a shell construct, per comments:

```
[ghoti@pc ~]$ cat strings.txt
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"bar";}
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:3:"baz";}
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:5:"snert";}
[ghoti@pc ~]$ while read line; do ./indexrepl foo test "$line"; done < strings.txt
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:4:"test";}
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:4:"test";}
a:1:{s:3:"foo";s:4:"test";}
[ghoti@pc ~]$
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to answer but as I said, I have to do that replace in a Wordpress SQL dump which contains lots of those serialized data to correct, so I can't unserialize/serialize my data with PHP like so.

Comment: If the script I wrote is used from within a bash script, it will generate reliably reserializable output.  Your question doesn't mention Wordpress or where this data comes from or where it's going, or whether PHP CLI is available on the host where you need to run this.

Comment: Updated my answer with an example.

Comment: I specified it was a "mysql dump containing PHP serialized values", the serialized representations of variables are into insert sql queries...